# Are all who are saved, saved equally?

Tags: soteriology

If two people are saved, are they "equally saved?" I don't doubt that both people are completely forgiven, but is it possible for one Christian to be more revered by God than another Christian? Is being saved a simple yes/no kind of thing or are there tiers to it?

This question is not to be confused with a question about being part of an elect or pre-destination.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/462/are-there-multiple-levels-to-heaven

Answer (score 7):

Well, many verses in the Bible don't refer to any kind of ranking, so I would think not. All of the verses in the famous *Roman Road* apply to everyone and one even makes it clear that Jews and Gentiles are equivalent.

> **Romans 10:13** (NLT)
>   12 Jew and Gentile are the same in this respect. They have the same Lord, who gives generously to all who call on him. 13 For “Everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.”

Hence, even though there ARE differing levels of rewards (see [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/462/are-there-multiple-levels-to-heaven)), everyone is equally saved.

Comment: Could you clarify on the answer ? I see the answer paradoxical. If there are differing levels of reward, how could everyone be **equally** saved ?

Comment: @Pacerier: The rewards depend on works whereas salvation depends on faith. You receive the same salvation no matter how much faith you have, but depending on the work you've done, you'll get particular rewards.

Comment: Ok I see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

There are some relevant parables that Jesus gave to talk about the coming age.

The first one is the parable of the talents (see **Luke 19**) where God gives to one faithful servant 5 cities, and to another servant 10 cities, according to their ability and effort on earth.

Also relevant is the parable of the day-laborers (**Matthew 20**), where all the laborers at every part of the day recieved the same wage, even those who had only been working for 1 hour.

I think what these parables show is that though all of God's servants will endter the kingdom, it will be filled with many people of many stations and rankings. Jesus said to His twelve:

> ...ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of
>   Israel.  **Matt. 19:28**

See also **Psalm 84:10**,

> I had rather be a doorkeeper in the house of my God, than to dwell in
>   the tents of wickedness.

Even in heaven, someone has to hold the door open. It is a role with less responsibilty, but it would be awesome to hold the door open for the Father! We would do well to consider how our actions today will affect our life to come, lest we merely avoid damnation and say as Job did, "I am escaped with the skin of my teeth."

Answer (score 1):

[1 Corinthians 3:11-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%203:11-15&version=NIV) talks about rewards being given for good works performed above and beyond the "foundation" of salvation through faith in Jesus -- or alternatively, suffering loss as a consequence for lack of good works (despite still being saved).

1 Corinthians 3:11-15 NIV:

> For no one can lay any foundation other than the one already laid, which is Jesus Christ. If anyone builds on this foundation using gold, silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw, their work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each person’s work. If what has been built survives, the builder will receive a reward. If it is burned up, the builder will suffer loss but yet will be saved—even though only as one escaping through the flames.