# Does the Catholic Church teach multiple levels of heaven?

Tags: catholicism, heaven

This concept of multiple levels of heaven is one I’ve heard from Protestants, so I was wondering if the Catholic Church teaches it?

---

Related: [Are there multiple levels to Heaven, for different levels of reward?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/462/are-there-multiple-levels-to-heaven-for-different-levels-of-reward)